# Disallow requests to a certain domain on shared hosting?

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting

Several of my websites are hosted on a shared server. The folder structure and domain assignment of my web space looks like this:

```
directory    assigned domain
-------------------------------------
/            x8967397.my-provider.com     (default domain)
/dir_1/      www.my-first-domain.com   =  x8967397.my-provider.com/dir_1/
/dir_2/      www.my-second-domain.com  =  x8967397.my-provider.com/dir_2/
```

The domain `x8967397.my-provider.com` is the default domain that comes with my hosting plan. It always points to the root directory of my web space and cannot be turned off or set to another folder. The result is that the website with the URL `www.my-first-domain.com` can be accessed by requesting `x8967397.my-provider.com/dir_1/`. That is, both URLs show the same website to the visitor.

I'd like to block access to the default domain (`x8967397.my-provider.com`), including all files and directores (e.g. `x8967397.my-provider.com/file.html` and `x8967397.my-provider.com/dir_1/`), without blocking the other domains (e.g. `www.my-first-domain.com`), but don't know how. If I block access to the root folder in htaccess, using `Deny from all`, all domains become inaccessible.

How can I tell my webserver to disallow requests to a certain *domain*, in this case the default domain?

Basically something like this:

```
<URL "x8967397.my-provider.com">
Deny from all
</URL>
```

---

*Edit*

There are .htaccess files in the folders `/dir_1/` and `dir_2`, which are the root folders for the custom domains `www.my-first-domain.com` and `www.my-second-domain.com`. Here are the rewrite rules from the .htaccess file of one of them:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^images/background\.png$ includes/adaptive-images.php

# redirects non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-first.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-first-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirects /index.php to /
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.my-first-domain.com/ [R=301,L]

# redirects missing files and directories to home (instead of error document)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-first-domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x8967397\.my-provider\.com$ [NC]
#exclude root dirs
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]+/?$
#exclude homepage
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
#forbid all other requests
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

This will return a 403  forbidden error if you visit the root `/` and root level directories `/foo/` and files of your domain ie: `http://x8967397.my-provider.com/foo/` will return a HTTP 403 error.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was not very helpful, I know. First, you have a whitespace after the caret. I'm not sure if that should be there. When I use your code (without the whitespace), only requests for `x8967397.my-provider.com` return 403, while `x8967397.my-provider.com/file.html` and `x8967397.my-provider.com/dir_1/` remain accessible. Re-reading my question, it may have been misleading. I'll edit.

Comment: The space was a typo . I have corrected it in my answer. Try the updated version now.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I have copied the code from your answer and only changed the domain name, and indeed the root domain (`x8967397.my-provider.com`) and a file immediately under the root domain (`x8967397.my-provider.com/file.html`) return 403, but when I visit a directory (`x8967397.my-provider.com/dir_1/`) or a file within a directory (`x8967397.my-provider.com/dir_1/file.html`), they display without error.

Comment: Do you have any other htaccess file that can conflict with this one?

Comment: Yes, see the edit to my question. As the subfolders in the root of `x8967397.my-provider.com` (e.g. `x8967397.my-provider.com/dir_1/`) are the root folders of other domains, there are .htaccess files for those domains in those folders. – I don't know how other hosting providers work, but this is how this one works. If you have multiple domains, and you want them to have different content, you have to point them at different directories within the default domain. Which makes all of them accessible as folders below that default domain. And that is what I want to prevent. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user57423 Your `/dir_1` `dir2/htaccess` files are the causes of the problem as they are overriding your parent htaccess rules. You can put the exact same rule in those folder htaccess files in order to block them .